# How to Read File from PersistentVolumeClaims in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, persistent-volume-claims

I have "file.txt" in my OpenShift PersistentVolumeClaims.
My StorageClasses is NFS.

Is it possible to access and read "file.txt" from my spring-boot code?
(This spring-boot code will be deployed on OpenShift and I'll mount the PVC to the DeploymentConfigs)

If yes, how can I do that? (I'm confused in how to retrieve the file from persistent volume from inside the code)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You mount the persistent volume in your pod [as described in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/). Then it's just a matter of opening a file at the correct path -- your application doesn't know or care about the fact that you're using a persistent volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @larsks said in the comment is correct:

> your application doesn't know or care about the fact that you're using
> a persistent volume

---

However, I used:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/pvc/mount/path/file.txt");
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

and:

```
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("/pvc/mount/path/file.txt");
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

Both **doesn't work**.

---

Below is what I use in the end:

```
Path file = Paths.get("/pvc/mount/path/file.txt");
InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(file);
```

Comment: Hello, 
Do you know How to write File from PersistentVolumeClaims in SpringBoot

Comment: @zoroglur Sorry for the late reply.. I think it's better to create new Question, but I will try answering.
I use this line of code:
File file = new File("/pvc/mount/path/file.txt");